# disable savefiledialog's filename box

Tags: c#, winforms, savefiledialog

I'm  using a `savefiledialog` to save files, but i don't want the user to be able to change the text in the filename field. My previous form shows them how the file(s) will be named. Is it possible to make the textbox uneditable? Or is my best choice just to make my own form that just allows the user to set a save directory?

Thanks!

Comment: A FolderBrowserDialog will show folders only http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [`FolderBrowserDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx) is probably a better choice.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to disable parts of the SaveFileDialog.  If you want to give users the option of specifying a directory to save to, use the [FolderBrowserDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx) instead.

You can use the [RootFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.rootfolder.aspx) property to set the starting folder.  Once the user clicks "OK", you can smilpy access the [SelectedPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.selectedpath.aspx) property to get the chosen path.